# How to show Bold for certain word in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: html, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I made Formula Field

```
If {CAMPAIGN_PRINTED.BYFIELD} = "Total" THEN  "<b> TOTAL </b>" 
ELSE {CAMPAIGN_PRINTED.BYFIELD}
```

but it is showing

```
<b> TOTAL  </b>
```

What is appropriate syntax for show?

**TOTAL**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula should work as expected, but the `Text Interpretation`-option on the formula field must be set to `HTML Text`.

Right-click on the formula field -> `Format Field...` -> `Paragraph` :

[image]